# Using java.util.List.sort with java.time.LocalDateTime compareTo method

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a `List` of users. Each user has a property called LastExtractJob, which is a `java.time.LocalDateTime`. I want to sort the user `List` based on LastExtractJob.

Here is my code

```
allUsers.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    final LocalDateTime o1DT = o1.getLastExtractJob();
    final LocalDateTime o2DT = o2.getLastExtractJob();
    if ((o1DT != null) && (o2DT != null)) {
        return o2DT.compareTo(o1DT);
    }
    return 0;
});
```

This has been working well for a while, but a new item in my user List is now causing this error to be thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

My user List contains many LastExtractJob null values, which I think is OK as LocalDateTime implements comparable. The objects being compared when the error is thrown are both null.

Can anyone spot the problem here?

EDIT: Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at com.company.app.AdminServlet.handleViewClientListState(AdminServlet.java:448)
at com.company.app.AdminServlet.doGet(AdminServlet.java:110)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: full stack trace posted

Comment: Reopened, as the other Q&A doesn’t even remotely tell how to solve this specific problem. Just having the same exception message, is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning zero, meaning both elements are equal, not only when both elements are `null`, but also when only one element is `null`. You should decide, whether `null` elements ought to be smaller or bigger, and return a value reflecting that order. Or use

```
allUsers.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getLastExtractJob()));
```

instead of your manual implementation. Use `nullsLast`, if you want to place `null` at the end of the list.

Comment: @MartínStraus if it looks correct, then upvote the answer ;-). btw Holger this is the first time in my StackOverflow experience that I've seen your answer downvoted... corrected that for you as I don't see a reason why it was downvoted +1 ;-).

Comment: You're right, this was the problem. I tested for when one value only was null and returned the appropriate value. This fixed the problem - thanks!

Comment: @Aominè I won't upvote unless i've _checked_ it's correct, which I didn't. That's why I said that it "looks" correct.